# Hobbit Xymon Enabled deleted host

Tags: linux, monitoring

Can anyone tell me how to enable a deleted host in xymon/hobbit using bb command? I deleted the wrong host by accident and want to enable it again so it will start graphing again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found that deleting the RRD files created by XYMON and restarting the servers and client fixed the problem.